# Wordpress fluent form date and time issues

Tags: wordpress, elementor, fluent

I have a Wordpress form using fluent form and I have issues that I want to fix about the form.
the issue is on the date and time picker, I want to have both option choose the date or give user the possibility to enter the date manually.

You can take a look the link below: https://parainage.diaobe.net/dakar/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkFaI.png)